# Is it possible to easily test what happens to your app once there is no room left on your device?

Tags: android, windows, testing, fiddler

I'm currently looking to see what happens to my app when there is no space left.

Is it possible to change a request using fiddler?

Is it possible to set permissions on how much space an app can use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Fiddler can alter any HTTP/HTTPS request. See http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-20/breakpoints-in-fiddler for how to do modifications manually, or http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse for info on how to alter requests programmatically.

It's not clear how this relates to exhausting the space on the device.